# Elasticsearch get multiple documents by uids over multiple indices

Tags: elasticsearch

The previous setting was all documents of one type were in the same index. But due to different forms (conceptually) of types, and for backing up purposes, I need multiple indices of a single type.

They will all be in the form *_feed*. While this setting is great in some circumstances, for

```
client.prepareGet(index, typename, ids).execute().actionGet(); // works great if you know in which index to search
```

it is useless, since no wildcards may be used. What I can do is use multiple multigets and interleave the results. This results in what I want, but increase the amount of queries significantly.
Assuming I know, for sure, only one document exist with a given index, is there a better way to query does than call a multiget on all _uids for each possible index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to develop a mechanism in your application that would allow you to deduce the index name from the id. But assuming that this is not possible or practical, you have pretty much only two choices. If you need realtime get, then your approach is the only way to do it. If realtime get is not a requirement, you can perform a search across all indices using [ids filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-filter.html). If the id list is small you can benefit from using [routing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html#search-routing) on your search query. This way the search request will only be dispatch to the shards that might contain any of the ids listed in the query. However, if the list of ids is big enough to span most of the shards, it will not provide any benefit.

Comment: Any clue on what `small` is? Are you talking about <10, <100, <100xx? Any idea on the overhead? I'm afraid deducing anything from the _uid is not an option, since I create the _uid based on some values from the document in order to improve searching (to clarify this: I get some documents multiple times, some values change (others, hopefully, not), by hashing some values I get a (pretty) unique identifier). So when I prepend the index name, this searching will fail

Comment: By small I meant <= an average number of shards in index. Basically, if you have 5 shards and 2 ids, it makes sense to use routing since in worse case scenario you will hit only 2 shards instead of 5 per index. If you have 10 ids it's more likely that that these 10 ids will belong to 5 different shards, so you need to hit all 5 shards anyway, so specifying routing will be just a waste of time. Figuring out the overhead is tricky since a lot of different variables are involved. I think the best way would be to test it and see how it performs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'll revisit your answer in a later phase, 'cause I suspect the `routing` will be relevant by then. For now I'll do a performance test between my current situation and the `ids filter`. Btw, I didn't find on the `es`site, does the `ids filter` return its values in the some order as the input? With order words, will is return a (sort of) `null response` on an uid which it doesn't find, like for multiget or `bulkX`?

Comment: The ids filter just returns record that match ids. You will need to wrap it into a constant score query that will give all ids the same score and therefore ids will be returned in their "natural" order (which is basically the order they exist in the index). You will not get any null responses for uids that were not found - they will simply not appear in the response.